# Repeating the whole Cucumber scenario with only one different step

Tags: cucumber

I have scenario like this:

```
Scenario 1
  step A
  step B
  ...
  step X
  ...
  step M
  step N

Scenario 2
  step A
  step B
  ...
  step Y
  ...
  step M
  step N
```

In short, there are 10-ish steps before and after the step `X` or `Y`. I would like to remove the duplication of repeated steps somehow, but not sure what would be the best way. I came up with this solution:

```
Scenario 1_2
  step A
  step B
  ...
  step X if env set
  step Y if env unset
  ...
  step M
  step N
```

So I can control if step `X` or `Y` is executed via the env.

Is there any better way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Take each step

Implement the step as a call to a helper method

Create a step that aggregates several steps and implement that as a series of calls to the helper methods you previously created.

Now use that step in your scenarios.

You scenarios will end up as something like

```
Scenario:
  Given A, B, C and D
  When X
  Then ...

Scenario:
  Given A, B, C, and D
  When Y
  Then ...
```

and now you have simple scenarios with no duplication of lots of steps.

You can (and should) apply this pattern all the time, and use this idea of abstraction (which is a fundamental part of language) to make your cukes simpler and shorter.

Comment: I know I can create an uber-step that will call all others, but I want to avoid this. I don't want to solve this in implementation, but in the Cucumber definition

Comment: It's not an über step. It's a step like any other that calls a helper method. The helper method then makes other calls to helper methods which results in your über functionality. This is a fundamental programming technique. Every Given in Cucumber has to build on previous When's. If you login you have to have registered. You don't put all the details of registering in every feature where you login, you abstract out the A,B,C of registering into X. Its the same pattern

Comment: Thank you. One thing I don't like here is that steps definition and order are now moved away from cucumber into the implementation. The idea is to group steps that are repeated in the Cucumber definition. We still want to maintain the cucumber file, change orders, add more steps, and not switch to the implementation to do so. I was expecting to have something like `Steps Group` in Cucumber that would serve as a simple macro.

Comment: You should rethink that. A Cucumber Scenario should never be about HOW something is done, so you should not need to group steps and think about order and be doing that stuff in features - its just to clumsy and error prone. Each scenario should be succinct 3-7 lines with most scenarios being < 5 lines and just describe WHAT you are doing.  When you change HOW you do something the scenario should not change. Don't program in scenarios, they are not designed for that.

Comment: I agree @diabolist, it's not designed by me, neither I have much freedom to change.